# Kill process group not working

Tags: linux, debian, bash, kill

I'm on Debian GNU/Linux.
The man page for "kill" says I can use negative PID value to kill process group, but when running on command line, it does not work:

```
$ /bin/kill -9 -21581
/bin/kill: invalid option -- '2'

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]
etc.
```

When using the bash built-in kill, it works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because its the first PID, you need to preceed it with "--" otherwise it'll be mistook for an option.

```
kill -9 -- -21581
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Sorry. I found it documented on RHEL, but not on Debian.

Comment: @mehturt This is documented in the 'Common Options' chapter of the gnu coreutils doc [http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#toc_Common-options]

Comment: ‘--’
"--" Delimit the option list. Later arguments, if any, are treated as operands even if they begin with ‘-’. For example, ‘sort -- -r’ reads from the file named -r.